# Deleting data with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a delete function for my sql table, but the php backend code throws lots of errors. Ive tried it several ways and non seem to work.

```
session_start(); //starts the session
if($_SESSION['user']){ //checks if user is logged in
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in

}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    $StaffID=$_GET['StaffID'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM volunteer WHERE StaffID = '$StaffID'" ;
    if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
        echo"Record deleted successfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql.";
        mysql_error ($link);
    }
    mysql_close();
} 


This seemed to work, how would I then get this function to return me to the original table with the record deleted?
```

Comment: what errors did it throw? Does your user have permission to do `delete` requests on your table?

Comment: **Warning**: You are open to `mysql injection` use prepared statements to secure it. Even more important, **do not** use `mysql_` functions anymore, they are *very* outdated, wich leads to security issues aswell. (*Note:* It's deleted from PHP7) Use `mysqli_` *or* `PDO` instead!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `DELETE * FROM volunteer WHERE StaffID = '$StaffID';`?

Comment: or `$sql = 'DELETE FROM volunteer WHERE StaffID="' . $StaffID . '"';`

Comment: one way I like to test php->sql like this is to echo the statement (eg `echo $sql;`, then copy/paste it into a mysql terminal and see if it works.

Comment: Or, `DELETE FROM volunteer WHERE StaffID=?` and use prepared statements instead of giving quick fixes to a never ending issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to recycle your PHP knowledge. There is a lot of things in it that are not used anymore, for example mysql library. Try to use PDO in the next projects.

There are a few problems with your code.

1- In mysql_query function you are passing a variable $link that apparently is not defined before. So, you should check it.

2 - The order of the variables in mysql_query function is not correct. See the link below:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php

3 - You are using a constant or a string in your where clause. You should to use the variable defined one line before.

I saw theses problems. Fix them, try again and post the results,

Regards,

Comment: Edited and fixed. The record is deleted. How would I go about getting it to return to the same page with a refreshed table?

Comment: @jamesmorris if you got an answer to your question, then say thank you and mark the answer as accepted. Do not be rude and ask follow-up questions. Any follow up question must be asked as a separate question.

Comment: No intension of bein rude, apologies. Thanks for all the help